# Get array stored in MongoDB by property

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, express

The array stored in my MongoDB looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "name": "X",
        "age": "2",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-29T22:22:49.491Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-29T22:22:49.491Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "name": "A",
        "age": "3",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-28T22:22:49.491Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-28T22:22:49.491Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "name": "B",
        "age": "2",
        "createdAt": "2020-02-29T12:22:49.491Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-02-29T12:22:49.491Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

As you see, 2 objects have same `age` as 2 and 1 have `age` as 3. I want to query from node.js by `age`, so that when I query by `age` 2, I get an array with objects having `age` 2. Currently `findById` works for me with query as `id`.

Here is the code:

```
exports.findByAge = (req, res) => {
    Property.findById(req.params.propertyId)
        .then(property => {
            if (!property) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    message: "Not found " + req.params.propertyId
                });
            }
            res.send(property);
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    message: "Not found with id " + req.params.propertyId
                });
            }
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving property with id " + req.params.propertyId
            });
        });
};
```

How do I query by `age`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should refer to [Find Documents with a Query Filter in Mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) and use it for filter document with `age` field. and read this link for [Comparison Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/).

```
exports.findByAge = (req, res) => {
    Property.find({ age: { $eq: req.params.age } })
        .then(property => {
            if (!property) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    message: "Not found " + req.params.propertyId
                });
            }
            res.send(property);
        }).catch(err => {
            if (err.kind === 'ObjectId') {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    message: "Not found with id " + req.params.propertyId
                });
            }
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: "Error retrieving property with id " + req.params.propertyId
            });
        });
};
```

and you can sorting coming data with [cursor.sort()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) add it after `find`.

```
Property.find({ age: { $eq: req.params.age } }).sort({ _id: -1 })
```

Specify in the sort parameter the field or fields to sort by and a value of 1 or -1 to specify an ascending or descending sort respectively.